# How make a persistent connection on your web server using sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, http, tcp, server

I make a web server on sockets. I want to support persistent connections.

When I write in the address bar of the browser a request to the server (on the localhost) in the headers I see "Connection: keep-alive", but the browser displays the data sent only after the connection is closed. I even do a "flush" on the connection (in python you can create a connection file and make a "flush" on it). I guess I don’t quite understand how sockets should behave in the persistent connection.

Please, help me figure out. If it is possible with a Python code examples. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: This is rather broad for a SO question. IMHO, you should study the HTTP protocol. A response is expected to be completed either when the server closes the connection or when the number of bytes declared in the `Content-length` header have been sent. If you do not provide correct headers, the browser can only wait for the connection to be closed.

Comment: I've removed the second part of your question since it was totally unrelated to what you asked first. Please don't pack anything you want to know into a single question but stay focused to on thing. If you need more help ask a second question instead.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I don’t quite understand how sockets should behave in the persistent connection

This seems to be the case. Persistent HTTP connection just means that the server is **may** keep the TCP connection open after sending the HTTP response in order to process another HTTP request and that the client **may** send another request on the same TCP connection **if** the TCP connection is still open by the server. Both server and client might decide to not send/receive another request and close the connection whenever it is idle (i.e. no outstanding HTTP response).

Persistent HTTP connection in no way change the semantics of HTTP from a request-response protocol to "anything sockets can do". This means the way you want to use persistence is wrong.